# How to document with JSDoc that a string variable will be used as a key in object variable?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Consider the following code:

```
/**
 * Adds a numeric value to given object using name as key
 * @template T
 * @param {T} obj
 * @param {string} keyName
 * Trying to tell JSDoc that the variable will become a key
 * @returns {{"keyName": number} & T}
 */
function testAddAttr(obj, keyName) {
  obj[keyName] = 1;
  return obj;
}

const testResult = testAddAttr({str: "hello"}, "num");
// here I expect IDE to know that testResult.num is a string
```

Now I don't really like doing things like this when I don't have to, but for example when processing command line input params and other non-typed data, it is sometimes needed. I can also see that typescript imported code that can be seen by my IDE (but the runtime is using plain JS) can do things like this.

In the above example, I tried to put `keyName` in quotes, that didn't work. Is there a way to do this? Some kind of `valueOf` operator?